# Getting faster inferences times the faster I call the function

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using PyTorch to inference an image at speed. What I noticed, which may be more of a python measurement issue, is that the faster I run images through my pipeline, the faster each inference is on average.

Posted below is the code and how I am measuring the time it takes to run each inference. When running at 10 Hz or so, the average time per 1000 inferences is about 1ms. When running at 1000 Hz, the average time per 1000 inferences is 500-600 us. So there is a significant boost. This happens on both CPU and GPU inferencing.

I think it has to be 1 of 3 things:

1. I am measuring incorrectly
2. There is some sort of performance boost you get from calling inference faster
3. Some other piece of code in the same multiprocess is hogging the GIL, but only when going slower? (last one doesnt make sense to me)

Any ideas?

```
try:
    self.new_img = image_queue.get(False)
    t1 = timeit.default_timer()
    decision = self.inference_model(self.new_img)
    self.total_time += timeit.default_timer() - t1
    self._counter += 1

    if self._counter % 1000 == 0:
        print("Avg Time:", self.total_time/1000)
        self.total_time = 0
except queue.Empty:
    pass
```

```
def inference_model(self, img):
    outputs = self.model(img)
    _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
    self.output = outputs.data.tolist()[0]
    return predicted.item()
```

Edit:

Based on a comment here, I went back and realized that perhaps its my try/except around the queue that is causing the issue. This is how the code looks (edited above)

Edit2:

Changed to get() from get(False), still getting the same behavior

Comment: How are you controlling the inference frequency during tests?

Comment: I am triggering a camera with a function generator and passing the image down to the code above via a queue, which is in a different multi-process.